# Weird Behavior while missing an await keyword generates error: Cannot access a disposed context instance

Tags: async-await, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mediatr

I recently ran into this error. I have never came across this before so wondering!

```
Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'OrderDbContext'.
```

The only thing i missed which produced this error is the `await` keyword in the controller action method before `_mediator.Send(checkoutCommand);` Once I added the `await` keyword this error vanished.

What (the heck) is wrong with missing this await keyword? The error does not explicitly state that. Can someone explain why missing an await keyword cause an error that database context is disposed?

Controller Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Checkout(CheckoutOrderCommand checkoutCommand)
{
    **var id = _mediator.Send(checkoutCommand);**
    return CreatedAtRoute("Get Order by Id", id);
}
```

CQRS Mediatr Instructions

```
public class CheckoutOrderCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<CheckoutOrderCommand, int>
{
    private readonly IOrderUow _orderUow;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public CheckoutOrderCommandHandler(IOrderUow orderUow,
        IMapper mapper)
    {
        _orderUow = orderUow;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }


    public async Task<int> Handle(CheckoutOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var order = _mapper.Map<Order>(request);
        
        // Populate base entity fields
        order.CreatedBy = Constants.CurrentUser;
        
        // create new order
        var newOrder = await _orderUow.AddOrderAsync(order);
        
        return newOrder.Id;
    }
}
```

Unit of work implementation

```
public class OrderUow : IOrderUow
{
    private readonly OrderDbContext _orderContext;
    public OrderUow(OrderDbContext orderContext)
    {
        _orderContext = orderContext;
    }
    
    public async Task<Order> AddOrderAsync(Order order)
    {
        try
        {
            await _orderContext.Orders.AddAsync(order);
            await _orderContext.SaveChangesAsync();                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return order;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception? Where is `OrderDbContext` being disposed? A missing `await` causes the code to continue without what should have been awaited being complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing an `await` without explicitly handling the task that is returned will mean that the code calling the asynchronous method will not create a resumption point and instead will continue executing to completion, in your case leading to the disposal of the `DbContext`.

Asyncrhronous code is multi-threaded behind the scenes. Think of it this way, your web request enters on Thread #1 which creates a DbContext instance via an IoC container, calls an asynchronous method, then returns. When the code calls an `async` method, it automatically hands that code off to a worker thread to execute. By adding `await` you tell .Net to create a resume point to come back to. That may be the original calling thread, or a new worker thread, though the important thing is that the calling code will resume only after the `async` method completes. Without `await`, there is no resume point, so the calling code continues after the `async` method call. This can lead to all kinds of bad behaviour. The calling code can end up completing and disposing the `DbContext` (what you are seeing) or if it calls another operation against the `DbContext` you could end up with an exception complaining about access across multiple threads since a `DbContext` detects that and does not allow access across threads.

You can observe the threading behaviour by inspecting `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` before the `async` method call, inside the `async` method, then after the `async` method call.

Without the `await` you would see Thread #X before the method call, then Thread #Y inside the `async` method, then back to Thread #X after. While debugging it would most likely appear to work since the worker thread would likely finish by the time you were done with the breakpoints, but at runtime that worker thread (Y) would have been started, but the code after the call on thread X would continue running, ultimately disposing of your DbContext likely before Thread Y was finished executing. With the `await` call, you would likely see Thread #X before the method call, Thread #Y inside, then Thread #Z after the call. The breakpoint after the async call would only be triggered *after* the async method completes. Thread #X would be released while waiting for the `async` method, but the  `DbContext` etc. wouldn't be disposed until the resumption point created by awaiting the `async` method had run. It is possible that the code can resume on the original thread (X) if that thread is available in the pool.

This is a very good reason to follow the general naming convention for asynchronous methods to use the "Async" suffix for the method name. If your Mediator.Send method is `async`, consider naming it "SendAsync" to make missing `await` statements a lot more obvious. Also check those compiler warnings!  If your project has a lot of warnings that are being ignored, this is a good reason to go through and clean them up so new warnings like this can be spotted quickly and fixed. This is one of the first things I do when starting with a new client is look at how many warnings the team has been ignoring and pointing out some of the nasty ones they weren't aware were lurking in the code base hidden by the noise.